How to create a list of elements that are present in one list but the other?
I have two lists of strings forbiddenList & inputList and I want to create another list that contains only elements from inputList that are not in forbiddenList
For now I do it as follows:
    List<String> finalList= new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (String ele : forbiddenList) {
        if (!inputList.contains(ele))
            finalList.add(ele);
    }

How to do it in a better way probably using either list as the returned results and so without the need to create another resulting list (not using Java 8 inline methods)
Thanks.

Do you have to use lists? Using sets would be better here

What does "better" mean?

and I want to create another list that contains only elements from inputList that are not in forbiddenList Wouldn't that merely be a copy of 'inputList' (or inputList itself)

The description does not match the code. In the code you insert elements from the forbiddenList into the finalList. You should iterate over inputList

Collections has native removeAll
method to remove the items of one list from another list.
inputList.removeAll(forbiddenList);


(the code of which will be much like what the OP posted, but in reverse and after the redundant step of combining two lists that are currently not together and don't belong together)
